# Python method to compare 2 values of 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to compare 2 columns from 2 different csv files but when they match in a specific row I want to append another column to 1 file from where it gets its values from the other file.

I tried the code below which works but some columns that have matching values didn't get matched and I don't know why. I'll add screenshots below to show more what got matched and what didn't.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(r"D:\PFE\Final_comparing\steps_algo\second_file_with_code.csv")

df2 = pd.read_csv(r"D:\PFE\Final_comparing\fichiers_ventes\I660124N.csv")

df1_exploded = df1.explode('Sales Names')
df1_exploded['Sales Names'] = df1_exploded['Sales Names'].str.strip("[]").str.replace("'", "")
merged_df = pd.merge(df2, df1_exploded[['Sales Names', 'code']], how='left', left_on='nom de produit', right_on='Sales Names')

merged_df.drop(columns=['Sales Names'], inplace=True)

merged_df.to_csv("I66_coded_v2.csv", index=False)
```

This is the output when it works
[image: This is the output when it works]
This should have been matched with the name in the image below
[image: This should have been matched with the name in the image below]
This one here the name exists in the list in the picture above
[image: This one here the name exists in the list in the picture above]

Comment: Have you carefully checked some examples of failed matches? The matches must be exact, ensure you don't have a different case of extra characters (spaces?). In any case your question is missing a [mre].

Comment: @mozway I have double checked and no there's no extra characters and the are the same

Comment: Then demonstrate it to us, provide a [mre], images of code/data are not acceptable